# timeout while dropping database - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.4, mongodb-3.6

Getting time out issue while dropping database from mongoDB. Database size is around 200GB.

```
   {
          "code" : 46,
          "ok" : 0,
          "errmsg" : "timed out waiting for DBNAME.Collectionname"
   }
```